# Is it possible to get the optional parameter values from a constructor using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

Given a class like this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
  {
      private string _name;
      private int _someInt;
      private int _anotherInt;

      public SomeClass(string name, int someInt = 10, int anotherInt = 20)
      {
          _name = name;
          _someInt = someInt;
          _anotherInt = anotherInt;
      }
  }
```

Is it possible using reflection to get the optional parameter's default values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets take a basic program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo();
    }
    public static void Foo(int i = 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi"   +i);
    }
}
```

And look at some IL Code.

For Foo:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Foo([opt] int32 i) cil managed
{
  .param [1] = int32(0x00000005)
  // Code size       24 (0x18)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "hi"
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_000c:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object,
                                                              object)
  IL_0011:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

For Main:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  call       void ConsoleApplication3.Program::Foo(int32)
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

*Notice that main has 5 hardcoded as part of the call, and in Foo*. The calling method is actually hardcoding the value that is optional! The value is at both the call-site and callee site.

**You will be able to get at the optional value by using the form:**

`typeof(SomeClass).GetConstructor(new []{typeof(string),typeof(int),typeof(int)})
                .GetParameters()[1].RawDefaultValue`

On MSDN for DefaultValue (mentioned in the other answer):

*This property is used only in the execution context. In the reflection-only context, use the RawDefaultValue property instead. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue.aspx)*

And finally a POC:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var optionalParameterInformation = typeof(SomeClass).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(int) })
   .GetParameters().Select(p => new {p.Name,  OptionalValue = p.RawDefaultValue});

   foreach (var p in optionalParameterInformation)
      Console.WriteLine(p.Name+":"+p.OptionalValue);

   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/10/31/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-1-optional-parameters.aspx

Comment: lol - fixed the typo in constructor...was copying from another example I'd used on SO ;O

Comment: That will make a difference. In that case you will want to use [type].GetConstructor() instead of GetMethod().

Comment: Answer updated to account for the difference. You can change 1 to 2 to get the third optional value. I tested this and it works on my machine, and DefaultValue [instead of RawDefaultValue] should also work depending on the context of the reflection.

Comment: My issue was the fact that I only specified the `typeof(string)` when I needed to specify all of the types.

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultValue` of the `ParameterInfo` class is what you are looking for:

```
var defaultValues = typeof(SomeClass).GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters().Select(t => t.DefaultValue).ToList();
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Actually in your first post, you made reference to some AbstractClassToTestSomeClass method, while in the edited version its the constructor with optional parameter, check out the edit above